# Angular get images returning mime type of text/html and 404

Tags: php, angular, image, angular6

1. I saved images name on MYSQL table
2. I use *ngFor to iterate through 
   images name returned

   ```
   <div *ngFor="let img of 
   imageName><img 
   src="../../../asset/images/
    profile/{{img.name}} >
    </div>
   ```

I can confirm that this image exist. and some times, untill I saved my code..'Ctrl s'. That is when the image displays. But when the application is loaded. It returns 404 with mime type text/html.
I do not know if it is from the names returned or angular 6

Comment: If you check the URL it's requesting in the developer tools network tab, does it look correct? Also, should it be `asset`, or `assets`?

Comment: If you get a 404, the mimetype you're getting is as expected.

Comment: The url is correct. The funny part is that. If i save my code "Control S". The image shows